# How to stub static void methods that has no arguments?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

```
PowerMockito.spy(SomeClass.class);   
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(SomeClass.class);
SomeClass.StaticVoidMethod();
```

This does not seem to work. I get UnfinishedStubbingException.

Comment: Needing to mock static methods is a common code smell suggesting you should move this method into an interface or class, so that you can introduce a mock or fake instance and pass *that* into the code you're testing, rather than mock the static method globally.

Comment: Cannot alter the code, as it is not written by me. Any suggestions on how to test this?

Comment: "it is not written by me."  It comes from a third-party lib ? Please give more details.

Comment: And beyond that: when all the answers are not helping; then put up a [mcve] that shows your problem. We can't really help with such insufficient input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you really can't change the "code under test"; and that static call gives you problems, then your only option is to use PowerMock; and as the other answer outlines, their [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) gives an exact description how to do that (and for the record: read and follow that instructions carefully).

But you have to understand that PowerMock is "more expensive" compared to other mocking frameworks; for example: you can't combine PowerMock with Mockito nicely. Of course there is PowerMockito; but that tooling only works with pretty much outdated versions of Mockito.

Long story short: PowerMock can solve this problem; but don't be surprised when it creates *other* problems for you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(SomeClass.class)
```

This will mock all methods of this class.

For more information go through this link
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

Cheers!!!

Comment: @mhsree Then you are missing one of the steps listed in there. Be assured: PowerMock is a horrible tool, but when you use it correctly, it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't quite finish your Mockito sentence.  You forgot to tell the stub what method it'll invoke.

To complete the sentence...don't forget the method call at the end.

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(SomeClass.class).StaticVoidMethod();
```

Comment: How else can I do that?

Comment: Why an answer ? :)

Comment: @mhsree:  I've revised the answer; I felt like it was apparent as to what I referred to but I realize now that wasn't the case.

Comment: I cannot invoke the method that way

Comment: Doesn't compile

Comment: @VivekChavda:  If you took the above code and copied it ***verbatim*** into your IDE, not only would it not compile, but you would have not gained anything from my example above.